# Get length between two coordinates?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to get the length between two coordinates using a Raphael.js path.

If I for example have this path:

`M612 295 L690 429 L642 565 L540 432 L711 379 L763 502 L683 585 L480 612 L605 466 L717 318 L888 466 L756 586 L609 392 L835 248 L874 472 L927 622 L724 674 L708 403 L563 391`

Then I want to be able to get the length between `711 379` and `927 622`, is that possible?

Comment: that's a lot of numbers.. could you post a screenshot?

Comment: @fazo I just selected a bunch of cords on random. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/vfkcd.png) is the printscreen. Sorry for the background.

Comment: sorry, but i don't think it does

Comment: To bad, i really need a way to figure out the sub length to be able to calculate the speed of the red dot along the path.

Comment: Can't you just use the Pythagorean theorem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Comment: @Ican Then I've to do the calculation for each line, which in my case is over a 100.

Comment: @Oleander: How often are these lengths calculated?  It shouldn't take that long to calculate the lengths of over 100 lines.

Comment: @Ivan Yeah, you're right. The calculation is only being done once. Thanks for the tip, I'll post the final code here when I'm done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), just like [Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759316/ivan) pointed out, is the way to go.

I created [this lib](https://github.com/linjekoll/raphael.coordinates.js) to solve my problem.

Here is an example.

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
var path = paper.path("M10 10 L90 90 L21 18 L19 31");

path.getLengthBetweenCoordinates({
  y: 10,
  x: 10 
}, {
  x: 21,
  y: 18
});

/* => 212.86170582141557 */
```

Comment: Does this work also for curved paths, for example - created using the "T" command (and not the "L" command used in your example)?  Thanks !